# Determine trigonemtric ratios given angle

Tags: trigonometry

Determine the primary trigonometric ratios for -pi/2

The answer is -1 and the solution is probably really simple, but I was wondering how do you get it?

Comment: $\sin,tan$ are odd functions unlike $\cos$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, because circles are weird. I mean, we all know it's because $sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}) =-1$ and we can solve it by looking at the unit circle, because that's how we one day defined, $sin$, $cos$ and by doing so $tan$. If we take an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ **downward**, or anti-clockwise, (because it's negative), and we take the y-coordinate of that point, then what we actually did is simply calculating $sin(-\frac{\pi}{2})$ resulting into -1. That's how you get it.